# Theorem 3.6 in Sec. 3.9 in Apostol's Calculus vol. 2, 2nd edition: (How) does such a matrix exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations, linear-transformations

Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the real Euclidean $n$-space, let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ be the unit coordinate vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$; that is, let 
$$e_1 \colon= (1, 0, \ldots, 0),$$
$$e_2 \colon= (0, 1, \ldots, 0),$$ 
and so on 
$$e_n \colon= (0, 0, \ldots, 1).$$

Then there is a unique linear transformation $T \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $T(v_k) = e_k$ for each $k = 1, \ldots, n$.

How can we find an $n \times n$ matrix $B$ such that $v_k B = e_k$, where $v_k$ and $e_k$ are to be regarded as a row matrices for each $k = 1, \ldots  n$?

Answer (score 2):

Theorem 2.12 in Apostol says, if $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is any basis (not just the standard basis) for a vector space, and $u_1,\dots,u_n$ are any vectors, there is a unique linear transformation $T$ such that $Te_k = u_k$.

Apply this statement to the basis $v_k$ (by Thm 1.7, $v_k$ form a basis): there exists a unique linear transformation $T$ such that
$$
Tv_k = e_k,
$$
and $B$ is just the matrix associated with this linear transformation in this basis (such a matrix always exists, see section 2.10).

The critical part is that the $v_k$ form a basis; if they didn't, there wouldn't be a $T$ (and so no associated $B$) such that $Tv_k = e_k$, and the whole argument doesn't get off the ground.

Comment: where does the matrix $B$ originate? I'd appreciate if you could take time answering my question fully and in detail.

Comment: but how do we know that such a matrix $B$ actually exists in the first place?

Comment: Let $C$ be a matrix whose rows are $v_k$. Is $C$ invertible?

Comment: Actually, Theorem 3.6 in Apostol's Caclulus vol. 2, 2nd ed., reads that the vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ are independent if and only if the matrix with these vectors as rows has non-zero determinant. So, we're not supposed to use this fact.

Comment: Ok, in view of what you are trying to prove, and what you can assume, I have changed my answer.

Comment: thank you so much for being so particular about answering my question; I really appreciate it, but I think I'm clear about the existence of the transformation $T$ and the fact that the $v_k$'s are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now if $B$ is the matrix associated with $T$ relative to the orderedbasis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ and $e_1, \ldots, e_n$, then how does it come about that $v_k B = e_k$ for each $k$, as has been asserted by Apostol? This is what stumps me.

Comment: I'm not sure why he chooses to associate $T$ with a $B$ like this, instead of the more usual $Cv_k = e_k$. But if you're comfortable with the construction of $C$, then it is just $B^T$: note that $(v_kB)^T = e_k^T$ so $Cv_k^T = e_k^T$ (here $v_k^T$ and $e_k^T$ are column vectors).

Answer (score 1):

The following matrix would work :  ${[v_1 | v_2 | ...| v_n]}^{-1}$ 
 Here , each $v_i$ is a column vector.

Comment: how does the matrix you've specified work? Could you please elaborate the entire process?

Comment: When we write doen a matrix, we know that the $k^{th}$ columan is the image of the $k^{th}$ basis vector.So, the matrix$ {[v_1 | v_2 | ...| v_n]}$ maps the standard basis vectors ${[e_1 , e_2 , ..., e_n]}  $to ${[v_1 , v_2 , ..., v_n]} $. So, there exists a unique inverse for this transformation which is going to map the vectors  ${[v_1 , v_2 , ..., v_n]}$ to ${[e_1 , e_2 , ..., e_n]}$ which is what I've given as the answer.